# Is it possible to harness energy from kugelblitz mergers?

Tags: energy, black-holes

As I understand it, the kugelblitz is a theoretical method of constructing microscopic black holes, wherein enough radiation is concentrated within one region that it can warp spacetime to become a black hole.

Therefore, it should be correct to say that a kugelblitz would have identical properties as a conventional black hole (formed from concentrated mass). The merger of two kugelbitzes would therefore release energy in the form of gravitational radiation, as in a conventional black hole merger. To the best of my knowledge, however, microscopic black holes evaporate immediately after they are created, and extracting energy from such a merger may be impossible.

Is it theoretically possible that high-energy lasers could be used to create kugelblitzes by an advanced civilization, and the mergers of such kugelblitzes be used as a source of energy?

Comment: How would it be a source of energy? You can't get more energy from your kugelblitzes than what you use to create them. (And of course the high energy lasers are bound to waste energy as heat, too). BTW, you may enjoy playing with the [Hawking radiation calculator](https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator) to get an idea of the temperature, lifetime, & other parameters of various sized black holes.

Comment: Please do not edit questions to ask a different question when there are already answers present (that you even accepted!) that answer the original version. Just ask a new question instead.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thank you for the advice. Should I just delete the question, since it doesn't seem to be useful in its current state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

There is a similar problem, called Scientific Breakeven, with [Inertial confinement fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_confinement_fusion). There, small capsules of H are raised to extremely high temperatures so that fusion converts H to He and releases energy. The capsules are essential truly tiny  H bombs, about the size of a pinhead, and weighing about $10$ mg.

They are detonated with very large lasers that hit from all sides. The lasers heat the surface very quickly. The vaporized surface flies away, creating a reaction force that compresses the pellet. It is like a spherical rocket that drives the pellet towards its center, compressing it to perhaps $100$ times the density of water. This is accompanied by shock waves that heat the center enough for fusion to occur.

Or so the theory goes. In practice, there are endless complications and instabilities that prevent it from working as well as one would hope. Fusion has been made to occur. But so far it takes more energy to power the lasers than you get from the fusion of the pellet.

Note that H is the fuel that "burns" to release energy. The lasers are the "matches" that ignite the fuel. Scientific breakeven is a matter of efficiency - not using more engine to light the match than you get back by burning the fuel.

---

Creating black holes from lasers is different. Here lasers concentrate so much light energy in one spot that it collapses, generating a black hole. Then you manipulate the black holes so they give off energy, which you harvest.

In this case, energy from the lasers creates the "fuel", and then you get as much of that energy as you can back from the fuel. But you can never get more energy back than originally went into creating it. You might call this a problem of "theoretical breakeven".